# Ruby—unpack hash into list of arguments

Tags: ruby, rspec, hashmap, parameter-passing

### Question

How do I turn

```
arg2 = {a: "a", b: "b"}
method(arg1, arg2)
```

into this:

```
method(arg1, a: "a", b: "b")
```

### Background

---

I'm trying to make a `double` in `RSpec`, which takes arguments like this:

```
let(:dummy_obj) do
  [ double("my dummy object", name: "Mr. Jo", height: "10ft", etc) ]
end
```

The first arg is the name of the double object, after that you can add any number of key-value pairs which become the double's methods (e.g. `dummy_obj.height()` will return `"10ft"`).

I have a huge JSON hash that I want to use, where each first-level field in the JSON becomes a method in the double. So, I was hoping there'd be something like `*array` that unpacks each item in the hash as it's own hash.

Comment: is the `arg2` in line 2 supposed to be in `{}`s?

Comment: nope, thanks for spotting!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This:

```
method(arg1, a: "a", b: "b")
```

Is the same as this:

```
method(arg1, { a: "a", b: "b" })
```

Ruby lets you omit the curly braces (`{}`) when a hash is the last argument.

So your code already does exactly what you want:

```
arg2 = { a: "a", b: "b" }
method(arg1, arg2)
```

Answer (score -1):

I found this works:

```
double("dummy thing", *my_hash.map {|h| {h[0] => h[1]}} )
```

But it feels a bit hacky, still open to other suggestions.

:)

Comment: What is `my_array`? You didn't mention any arrays in your question.

Comment: sorry I started playing with arrays instead (fixed now), but actually this answer works for both arrays and hashes

Comment: This code will produce a method call equivalent to `double("dummy thing", { a: "a" }, { b: "b" })`, *not* `double("dummy thing", { a: "a", b: "b" })`.

Comment: That's true. I wasn't too clear on the scope of things, whether it was a single hash or a hash per key/value. This method creates an argument per key/value. (I ended up needed your code, with the single hash, but I think this method is useful to know also).